# GeoServer GML Direct

Tags: geoserver, wfs, gml

I have GML documents which I wish to serve with GeoServer WFS. Essentially, I want to be able to copy the documents to some place e.g. data_dir store and when a GetFeature is done have GeoServer return my GML document as-is but wrap it in wfs:FeatureCollection. I have the schema for the GML as well for the DescribeFeatureType. I'm struggling to figure this out though. Any pointers?

Comment: Add the data to a database, then use either App Schema (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/app-schema/index.html) for complex features or the Features Templating plug-in (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/features-templating/index.html) to map the GML schema you want the WFS to provide

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that easily, GML is a great interchange format but a very poor storage format as you have parse all of it to be able to serve parts of it.

Convert your GML into a database table or geopackage and add that to GeoServer.

If you absolutely must store GML, you would need to create a GML datastore extension from the GeoTools GML parser and add that to your GeoServer instance.

Comment: Would I be able to get back the original GML in this way ? Presumably you mean make postgis table, decode geometry out of my GML and insert into table which has geometry column and the GML as a varchar in another column ? I want to make sure that a WFS GetFeature gets back the original GML wrapped in WFS elements and not something created wholly by GeoServer

Comment: No, you'd get back valid GML but not necessaraly the original. If you just want to serve your GML use a web server

Comment: Problem with a web server is i'd have to implement the WFS protocol myself else no/few GIS clients will work with it plus there'd be no filter capability on the geometry

Comment: Even using the GML datastore, GeoServer would read the GML (if it's made of simple features, mind) and then build it from scratch in output. There is no direct "GML to GML" code path.